# Angular directive listen to element style change

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

Hi I Have this directive to add the background color to a element:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[bg-color]'
})
export class BgColorDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private el: HTMLElement;
  @Input('bg-color') backgroundColor: string;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
  }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.el.style.backgroundColor = this.backgroundColor;
    }

}
```

But in my case, I use it inside of another component `ngx-slick` and this component always change the style then it overwrite my directive result, so is there any way to apply my directive after the override?

Comment: when color should the changed?

Comment: take a look at observable and observer objects, you should be able to apply a trigger to the color change after the component is rendered (or whenever you wish)

Comment: @Aravind: I dont want this for dynamically chane color, I just want to use to establish the color, but If I use the `style="backgrond-color..."` in my element the `ngx-slick` override this rule, so i think that using a directive is the best solution for this

Comment: @FabioGuerrazzi, can you give me a example?

Comment: yes I was looking for it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274603/observable-of-component-attribute-changes-in-angular2

Comment: not sure how to do sorry, i remember I saw something similar, like to declare yor control observable then register after the page is rendered. You can assign the action (in your case to apply the color) and when you do register() the action takes effects, after the page rendering. I think that's the way but not sure

Comment: Can you create plunker to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use databinding so Angular will help keep the right color.  Change your directive to:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[bg-color]'
})
export class BgColorDirective {
  // update color at each input change
  @Input('bg-color') set inputColor(value){this.color = value};

  //data-bind to the host element's style property
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') color = 'white';//default color
}
```

You can still set the background color as you used to:

```
<ngx-slick bg-color="blue"></ngx-slick>
<ngx-slick [bg-color]="someProperty"></ngx-slick>
```

The difference now is that [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) will check and update the binding at each change detection cycle. It gets imported from @angular/core and it takes a string if you want to bind to a single property, or an object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I also found another solution changing the `ngAfterViewInit` by `ngDoCheck` and works for me, did your solutions is best that mine? this is my first directive I start learning with this.

Comment: @efirvida I don't have an opinion over which approach is better. I don't see one clear advantage one way or the other.